# How to Render Django MPTT TreeNodeMultipleChoiceField as A Tree

Tags: django, fancytree, mptt

I like to use `jquery` (i.e `jquery.fancytree`) or `bootstrap` library to rednder my form as a tree. I do not know how to!

I do not want to use `mptt_tags` `recursetree`. I need to use the Form and not the Model.

[Snapshot of the app with two level is shown.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OI7Wl.png)

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from mptt.forms import TreeNodeMultipleChoiceField

class RSMDriveForm(forms.Form):
    choices = TreeNodeMultipleChoiceField(queryset=RSMDriveModel.objects.all(),
                                        required=False,
                                        level_indicator=mark_safe("&nbsp;"),
                                        label="",
                                        widget=forms.widgets.SelectMultiple(),
                                        )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RSMDriveForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

**views.py**

```
def rsmgui_home(request):

    form = RSMDriveForm()
    context = {'drive_nodes': form }

    return render(request, "rsmgui_nav.html", context)
```

**rsmgui_nav.html**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="drive-form" method="post" action="" >
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for choice in drive_nodes.choices %}
        {{ choice }}
    {% endfor %}
</form>
```